# Setting up gmock with google test

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, googlemock

Could someone please help me compile the google test framework using google mock? Currently, I have this cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.11)
  include_directories(BEFORE SYSTEM
    "${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include" "${gmock_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
else()
  target_include_directories(gmock_main SYSTEM BEFORE INTERFACE
    "${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include" "${gmock_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
endif()


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# Locate GTest
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Link runTests with what we want to test and the GTest and pthread library
add_executable(runTests tests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(runTests gmock_main)
target_link_libraries(runTests ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread)
```

Currently I get this error: Cannot specify include directories for target "gmock_main" which is not  built by this project.

I know this is because of line 7 above, but if I remove the whole if-else statement I get this error: fatal error: gmock/gmock.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: You are locating GTest library with `find_package` ... but are using `gmock` library. Also, having `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)` means that only CMake 3.2+ can execute your `CMakeLists.txt`, so checking whether version is less than 2.8.12 is useless.

Comment: I thought about including the if-else statement because that's how it is shown on the google mock tutorial in their git repository, so I just copied it over.  What do you mean by locating the GTest library with find_package but I'm using mock? Dp you know what I should do?

Comment: If you follow [that tutorial](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googlemock#building-google-mock), it talks about [Incorporating Into An Existing CMake Project](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project), when you include GTest and GMock infrustructure with `add_subdirectory()`, not with `find_package()`. In that case "if-else statement" should come **after** corresponded `add_subdirectory` call, so `gmock_main` target will be defined at the point.

Comment: I don't understand where should I use [add_subdirectory] instead of [find_package]. If I change the [find_package] line what should I change it to?

Comment: If you have googletest sources under directory `gtest` in your sources, use `add_subdirectory(gtest EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)`. Otherwise take the code described in googletest manual [Incorporating Into An Existing CMake Project](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project).

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I am not sure if this is what I am looking for. I am trying to include gmock into the cmake build not gtest. Are you sure that this link is supposed to make it work?

Comment: GMock is part of GTest. `Are you sure that this link is supposed to make it work?` - It is documentation from the GTest/GMock developers. What about just trying?